# How to create and register text service?

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro

I have developed a IME as an ordinary windows 8 application  but I need to make this IMe available through out windows 8 .
So i did some research on it and i am supposed to create a Text service based on COM object using the IME which i created using C#.
and I need to register the COM object with in proc server

I am stuck creating a Text service 
I need some pointers on how to create a Text service and COM object.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will not help you a lot, but you'll get to know what will not work for you:
[Is it possible to make a WinRT service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10326459/is-it-possible-to-make-a-winrt-service)